# Core Bluetooth Framework: Incorrect value of battery characteristic

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I have created an application in IPhone that can act as a Peripheral. I have added several Services and Characteristics.For Battery characteristic, I have used the standard UUID "2A19". All other characteristic values are coming correctly in Central device except battery. It is showing 0 while i have given the value 60.Their is a possibility that it is colliding with IPhone battery characteristic. So is their any way to correct it ?

Service: Battery Service, UUID:180F

Characteristic: Battery Level, UUID 2A19 // This characteristic is associated with battery service

Comment: Which service is the characteristic associated with?  Can you show your `didReceiveReadRequest`?

Comment: i have updated my question and read is working fine with all characteristic except this one, do u still need the code of didReceiveReadRequest ?

Comment: You can't advertise a service that iOS already advertises.

Comment: But it is coming 0, at least iOS battery value will come.

Comment: I just ran a quick test app - If I advertise service 180F, characteristic 2A19 then all I can see is the phone's battery service and level.  If I advertise service 18FF, characteristic 2A19 then I can see the phone's battery service and level and service 18FF with my battery level

Comment: Thnx Paulw11 , but it's not in my hand to change service UUID, So i need to find some other solution.

Comment: You will need to use some other device as a peripheral, because iOS is already advertising service 180F